# How to show a div inside a if-else condition of another div in markup in asp.net?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a div (class=tab) with a span in it. I need to show this div inside a if-else condition of another div (with class= search). i.e. if some condition matches, this specific div should be displayed if not; this div should not be displayed. I had tried something like following which doesn't work. In the place of `div.tab style=(i == 0 ? 'display:block' : nil)`, I need to show this div with class tab.
Please help

```
    <div class="search">
        <% if (Model.IDs.Count() > 0) { %>
             <% if (some condition) { %>
                <div class="linksbar-selected"><a href="/abc/efg.aspx">
                PEOPLE</a></div>
                div.tab style=(i == 0 ? 'display:block' : nil) 
            <% } else { %>
                <div class="linksbar"><a href="/abc/efg.aspx">
                PEOPLE</a></div>
           <% } %>             
        <% } %>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <span class="ResultsFor"> RESULTS </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this??

```
<div class="search">
   @if (Model.IDs.Count() > 0) 
   {
      @if (some condition) 
      {
          <div class="linksbar-selected">
            <a href="/abc/efg.aspx"> PEOPLE </a>
          </div>
          div.tab style=(i == 0 ? 'display:block' : nil) 
       } 
       else 
       {
          <div class="linksbar">
            <a href="/abc/efg.aspx"> PEOPLE </a>
          </div>
       }          
    }  
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <span class="ResultsFor"> RESULTS </span>
</div>
```